# window.onload only works sometimes and alert() makes it work

Tags: javascript, html, http, svg, onload

This has something to do with a question I recently posted, so I'm sorry for asking again, but I just can't get my head around this. I really want to understand it and learn about it, since I'm just learning javascript/html.

I'm loading a svg into my html with **SVGInject** and then I use **Tippy.js** to get tooltips on my svg elements when hovering over them.

With window.onload it works **sometimes**, but not always. The error is:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

Reloading the page results in the error disappearing and appearing again.

I put an alert() into onload just to see what happens, and with the alert the error is gone and everything works. I'm so confused.

```js
window.onload = function (){
   //alert("test"); //why does this alert make everything work??
   /* SVG HIGHLIGHTS */
   svg_highlight('ebk_abp','abk_ab');
   svg_highlight('ebk_pbp','pbk_ab');

   /* SVG TOOLTIPS */ 
   svg_tooltip('ebk', "Eröffnungsbilanzkonto");
};
```

I realize it has something to do with the stuff not loading in the correct order, I simply don't understand how to approach this problem and why an alert() fixes everything..

I'm not sure if its allowed to post this, but here is my full project, so you can see for yourself:

https://github.com/rackuzi/DieAbbildung |  https://rackuzi.github.io/DieAbbildung/

Comment: because window.alert stops the thread until you click the button, thus allowing some asynchronous things happening in the background to finish before the code continues to run.

Comment: means you are adding your listener before the element is available. Does whatever you have fire events that it is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

The svg element doesn't exist yet, so you need to ensure that your code is executed in the correct order by using a callback.

You need to put the code to add the tooltips in the `afterLoad` property of the svg injection. See the documentation for `afterLoad` on this page. https://github.com/iconfu/svg-inject

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this makes sense. It sadly doesn't work though. The svg doesn't get displayed at all and I get this error: "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null" when I'm putting my functions into afterLoad.

Comment: Possibly the correct method is `afterInject`. I am not intimately familiar with this library but I am confident in the general premise of my answer.